# Notepad++, place grouped data into separate columns

Tags: excel, notepad++

I have data sets that have one column with several data IDs and another column with the corresponding value of all those IDs. So imagine some data on notepad++ that looks like this:

ID:123;ID:456;ID:789        12

How would I separate the data so the output would look like:

ID:123    12
ID:456    12
ID:789    12

I'm using notepad++ to perform this task. I'm not quite sure the key words for looking up my question, but this is what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

you can try regular expression search and replace. At the moment I cannot come up with a "fire and forget solution", but I can show how to replace one ID at the time.  (To replace the whole file you would press the keyboard shortcut for a few seconds an hold your breath.)  I fear that it will only work for a small number of IDs.

First make a backup of your file.

- Open the replace Dialog from the Search menu:
- Find what: "(ID:)([0-9]+);(.*) ([^ ]+)$" (without the quotes)
- Replace with: "\1\2 \4\n\3 \4" ( without the quotes)
- Check Search mode Regular expression.
- Click Replace a few times
- If it works as expected: Press Alt-R for few seconds.

[image]
With best regards,
Lars